# How to install hipchat on ubuntu 14.04 32 bit OS?

Tags: 14.04, unity, 32-bit

I need to install hipchat but i am unable to install it on 32 bit OS, is there any solution for that??? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they do not support 32 bit OS for Ubuntu.

But you can chat online using their web platform:

https://www.hipchat.com/sign_in

Comment: would there be any difference??

Comment: It works with the people using the desktop client if that is what you mean.

Comment: i am asked by my company to install hipchat

Comment: Yea, I use the web client with my company, and it works fine.